# parse unbalanced html file with Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am parsing partial of html files that are not with balanced html tags.

Say the first line is missing  in this partial html file. Is it possible that Beautiful Soup can still parse the rest of the files, and I can still extract the information insides of the different tags?

Thanks so much for the help.

```
Example Domain</title>   <!-- <====missing tag in this line -->

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
div {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #38488f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    div {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You will need to specify a parser that is not the default.  You can try `lxml` or `html5lib`. I don't have experience with either.

Comment: This is what I got when try to use lxml
"bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?"

I got the similar error message when switching to html5lib parser
"bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?"

I tried to pip install both libraries, but it failed. I am using OSX 10.9.5. Python3.4.4. Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Did you get an error message with pip? I did `pip install html5lib` and the following code works for me `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; soup = BeautifulSoup("<span>asdf", "html5lib"); print(soup)`

Answer (score 0):

Use any advanced parser (`html5lib` is more robust, but slower). The results will differ:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('foo.html'), 'lxml')
#<html><body><p>Example Domain   <!-- <====missing tag in this line -->
#<meta charset="utf-8"/>

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('foo.html'), 'html5lib')
#<html><head></head><body>Example Domain   <!-- <====missing tag in this line -->
#
#<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```